# group by line break and execute regex

Tags: python, regex

From one connector, I receive a very specific string format:

```
{#{123}#};{#{abc}#}\n{#{345}#};{#{def}#}\n{#{789}#};{#{ghi}#}
```

I can't change that format. Currently, I use the regex `(?s){#{(.*?)}#}`. This results in a list `["123", "abc", "345", "def", "789", "ghi"]`

Is it possible to get the output grouped by line? Something like `[("123", "abc"), ("345", "def"), ("789", "ghi")]` - I know i can also just use `split` in python. Is there any regex way? I tried a bit with [www.regex101.com](http://www.regex101.com), however couldnt find a solution.

Comment: Only if they are always in pairs on each line: `re.findall(r'{#{(.*?)}#};{#{(.*?)}#}', text)`

Comment: oh gosh. Thanks that is something really simple I forgot to try!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have pairs of matches on each line, you can capture them:

```py
re.findall(r'{#{(.*?)}#};{#{(.*?)}#}', text)
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/NiaZDj).

Output:

```
[('123', 'abc'), ('345', 'def'), ('789', 'ghi')]
```

Note you should not use `(?s)` DOTALL inline flag since it makes `.` match across lines.